# mp3 tune as background tune for android animation

Tags: android, animation, mp3

I am newbie to android, and want to set  mp3 tune as a background tune for an animation. I have an animation(clock) running as a frame animation and I want to set an mp3 file for that.
  the mp3 should play sequentially with the seconds hand in my clock animation,any Idea?

Thanks in advance....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android audio tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_playing_mediamp3_on_the_emulator-t156.html)

Comment: thanks a lot but how can we play this with the animation sequentially,I mean I have a clock animation and when the seconds hand moves the sound also should come sequentially with that

Comment: Use: mediaPlayer.seekTo(int msec) and mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Audio and Video processing on [Developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

Comment: thanks a lot but how can we play this with the animation sequentially,I mean I have a clock animation and when the seconds hand moves the sound also should come sequentially with that

Comment: Well, you can start playback immediately after view.startAnimation() and also use pause(), play() to synchronize.